# Draw a circle with a polygon geometry using the Mapbox Static API

Tags: python, maps, mapbox, geojson

I have Geojson polygons resembling circles that I am trying to display within a static mapbox map. To do this, I use the Datasets API to first create a blank database and then issue a put request to a mapbox route that adds a feature to the database. After completing the steps from the code below, I login to my mapbox studio dashboard and can see that the feature is there and accurate.

The mapbox documentation then says to use the Uploads API to convert it to a tileset, but after reviewing it, it seems very cumbersome and complicated for simply just drawing a circle on a map as it requires temporary AWS s3 bucket credentials.

Mapbox has a beta service named the Mapbox Tiling Service (MTS) API that is a recommended alternative to the uploads API and appears to be less cumbersome. It seems I need to upload the Geojson data from the datasets api to the MTS and then deliver it using the mapbox static API, but I am lost on how to do this?

I feel like using 3 separate api's to draw a circle on a map is too complicated. Any pointers on how to achieve this efficiently would be more than welcomed as I have been stuck on this for too long.

I know I can add overlays to the static API request but the polygon can be too large and make the request fail.

````
url = f"https://api.mapbox.com/datasets/v1/USERNAME/?access_token={os.getenv('MAPBOX_SECRET_KEY')}"
response = requests.post(url)
response.raise_for_status()
print(response.text)
resp = response.json()
dataset_id = resp['id']
data = MYGEOJSON
url2 = f"https://api.mapbox.com/datasets/v1/USERNAME/{dataset_id}/features/abc?access_token={os.getenv('MAPBOX_SECRET_KEY')}"
response = requests.put(url2, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
response.raise_for_status()```
````